# Options on redirection using servicestack API with old existing API

Tags: c#, iis, servicestack, httphandler

We have just implemented are new API using the amazing servicestack web API and so far it has been an easy transition.

However, as with all missing requirements we found out today that there is a third party module which cannot be changed which uses the old API.

As an example:

The new API is of the format

```
"http://localhost/api/v1/customer/update"
```

(which is a POST) and the old api is of the format

```
"http://localhost/services/LL_API/API_Customer.asmx/UpdateCustomer?
                                                       name="xxx"&address="yyy"
```

(which is a GET). In fact all the calls from the old API are GETs. Also there are about 30 old API calls which look nothing like the new API rest base format.

How would service stack handle this? I could put a httphandler that receives *.asmx requests and create new service stack web services to handle these or could I reuse the newly created web services?

The problem I have is the data returned will be different between the old and new API, so that is why I was thinking about creating a new set of web services.